# Can 2 users (family sharing, child and parent) share iCloud (key-value) storage?

Tags: share, icloud

I wrote app for my teenager (IOS - education). I need push updates (new exercises) and download progress. Now I have to connect unlocked iPhone to computer. And it is problem.

Can I write app (MacOS), that will use iCloud key-value storage with family sharing? 
Or is there any other possibility?

Comment: Dropbox might be your best option. Have you considered that? It has a fully featured API for reading and writing files to a shared area SwiftyDropbox is your google. Out of interest what does your app do?

Comment: Thanks. I thought it's paid. I'll try. The app is simple - it tests english (or french) words or fill-in grammar questions (from school book).

Comment: Mata, been working with dropbox API for over year, feel free to post me a question if you need some help getting off the ground. Easiest way in from my point of view is to start with the HTTP API and try out the CURL commands, you can use Alamofire to get something quickly working...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Dropbox works well.